# ADK 2011 and Arduino shields

Tags: arduino

I have been working around [ADK](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) and the [ADK board](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk.html) ([Arduino Mega2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560)). I am able to communicate over USB and talk to my board and vice-versa. Now I want to try out the same thing over [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi). I see that there are many Wi-Fi shields available. My questions are:

1. How do I know the shields I see online will work with [ADK 2011 board](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk.html)?
2. How do I connect the shield to my board?
3. Do I need to flash/program my ADK board and Wi-Fi shield separately?
4. I am not in favor of a particular ADK board. Any suggestions for another Arduino board using which I can talk to my Android phone via USB, Wi-Fi, [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth), Ble, etc. with or without shields.